# Using a dispatcher in creating a custom messagebox, however cant read the return value

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, if-statement, dispatcher

**WPF - C#**

I have a rather large issue. It is that I have developed a custom messagebox which works perfectly and all on normal threads. However in the background thread it throws an error saying its needs to be called by a STA thread. To resolve this you can dispatch the whole thing. But this in its self causes a problem because if the user clicks yes and you download a file or do something it will freeze or hang the UI. :

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
if (msgbox.ShowBox("Do you like bacon?", "Question") == "1")
msgbox.ShowBox("Yes");
else
msgbox.ShowBox("No");
}));
```

To get around this I tried the following:

```
if ((string)Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { msgbox.ShowBox("Update", "An update has been found, would you like to update now?"); })) == "1")
```

However the problem with this is that with the dispatcher in the way the if statment is unable to recieve the response from the messagebox and this causes the code to think no has been clicked or cancel has been pressed each time.

I've been trying to find a way to change my messagebox thread to a STA thread on it but with no look. I always get the this must be called from a STA thread for some UI elements on this bit of code.

```
public msgbox()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

If yo ucan come up with a solution to my headache of a problem I would be grateful. Its annoying as it is having to delagate every time I want to make a mesagebox. One last thing is that I copied across my messagebox code from my WFA projects and this project is my first proper WPF one. In WFA the messageboxes worked in the background worker with no problems and didnt require invoking or anything.

I also don't want to have to define a string response; each time either as that's also messy:

```
string response = "nothing";
if ((string)Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { response = msgbox.ShowBox("Update", "An update has been found, would you like to update now?"); })) == "1")
```

**EDIT: I think I've found a solution.**

Comment: I am doing this because much of the code in my background worker threads do require the user to choose options from yes or no along the way. Its hard to think of any other wey to do such a task and some are done in looping code. Where it may ask "Is this the correct folder?" if the user clicks no it keeps searching. That type of stuff.

Comment: _"Its annoying as it is having to delagate every time I want to make a mesagebox."_ but yes, it's what you have to do (probably few helpers methods can help you). UI is single thread. WFA application did work because MessageBox.Show() didn't check (bad) but it was wrong even there (try to type CTRL+C in a messagebox from a background thread).

Answer (score -1):

Used a middleman thread to create the message boxes and made them run on the original forms UI thread.

Comment: -1, give a code example to help with the issue, not just a one-line recommendation. Work on your answer and you'll get a +1.